# Parse facebook login isuse..ParseException e null and ParseUser null

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

i have used parse for login with facebook. and it work's properly also with login logout from facebook.

but with some unidentified case getting `user=null` as well `ParseException=null`.

[image]

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem once too. For me, the error was with the facebook authentication. Maybe there's an error with your connection to facebook. For me, my dns wasn't reaching facebook so i got this error.